# Importing a shapefile to Google Earth fails due to coordinates that are "invalid or outside the allowed interval"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth

I am trying to load a shapefile into Google Earth, but when I do, I get the message that "some functions were not imported due to coordinates that are invalid or outside the allowed interval" (my GE is set up in Danish, so the exact wording in English might be slightly different). When I click OK, I get the message "No functions were imported: There were no functions within the view File:[path and name of shapefile]".

I have tried reprojecting the shapefile both to WGS1984 and Web Mercator, but none of it helps. When I convert the shapefile to a KMZ (using the Layer to KML function in ArcGIS) and try opening this in GE, I do not get an error, but the view zooms to somewhere close to the North Pole (my points are in South East Asia) and nothing is displayed. In ArcGIS the points are located correctly.

I used to be loading shapefiles into GE all the time and don't remember even thinking about projections. But lately it has not been working, even though I have been trying lots of different shapefiles and different projections, and it never works.

I just uninstalled and reinstalled GE this morning and am now wokring with version 7.3.6.9345 (which I believe is the latest version), but this has not solved the problem.